# SQL Server 2017 on linux presenting system error 2

Tags: sql-server

The SQL Server 2017 running on a Ubuntu container started to present errors with permissions after the log file went full. Running

```
create database example
```

presents

```
CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) while attempting to open or create the physical file '/mssql-translog/translog/example_log.ldf'.

CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

I tried to change permissions directly on the container but it says the file system is read only.

Comment: your file system has path to "/mssql-translog" ?

Comment: It seems SQL server account (not your account) which is running the SQL Server doesn't have the proper permissions/rights on the folder which will contain the database log files. You need to give full control to the account which is running SQL Server. It will pass through this permissions error.